# Hpc doesn't get jobs after midnight

Tags: powershell, hpc

I have a matlab script that calls power shell and sends it a script to send a job to hpc server. 
I leave this script for hours sending jobs to the hpc even after I lock my computer and go home . 
I noticed that after midnight the server stoppes accepting new jobs from my computer until I come in the morning and unlock my computer , does anyone have an idea how can I get the server to accept jobs after midnight? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have proof that your computer didn't go to sleep itself? I.e. that the scheduled jobs continued being sent.

Comment: Yes, it prints to the screen the number of job, if it fails it prints zero. My screen is full of zeros until I log on again. Then immediately it starts getting job numbers

Comment: Any way to get an error code or message from the submission to the server? It could be anything - network issues, perhaps the target server shuts down, etc. Perhaps post the code being used to submit.